# How to I slow down API requests from Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, request, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets formula that fetches data from an API:

```js
function GETDATA(data){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://some.api.com/" + data);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  return content;
}
```

While everything works fine, this script fires an API call each time it's used in a cell (`=GETDATA("cars")` for example). This can quickly result in hundreds of API calls, at which the API gives up and responds with a code:

> 429: too many requests.

Is there a way, that I can slow these requests down in Google App Script? I already tried:

```js
function GETDATA(data){
  Utilities.sleep(150);
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://some.api.com/" + data);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  return content;
}
```

but this just results in all the cells waiting 150 ms and then executing all together again.

Comment: I would not use the formula at all.  Just run the script when you need it

Comment: If you don't need the API call every time that the Sheet is recalculated, then you'll need some other way to trigger the API call.  Or, have some kind of test in your function that determines whether the API call needs to be done or not before making it.  For example, Is there a value in another cell that can be checked that will tell you whether the API call needs to be done or not?  The other thing you could do is to put data from the API call into Cache, and only make a new call if Cache has timed out.